# Showing that if derivative is 0, function is constant ($f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

Here's the question:

Suppose that $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on the open subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and $Df(x) =0$ for all $x\in U$. Show that $f$ is constant on $U$.

My thoughts: 
First, I think it requires that the region is convex. Or path-connected. But anyways, beyond that I'm a bit stuck. MVT can't be applied to this case for obvious reasons.

Comment: You certainly need connectedness (or equivalently, path-connectedness, since connected open sets in $\mathbb R^n$ are path-connected).

Comment: Yeah, definitely an oversight on the professor's part. Also, hey, you go to UChicago. I'm trying to figure this out while in the Reg :|

Comment: I'm actually on leave at the moment. Best of luck with it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true as stated. You could take the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\le 0\\2&x>0\end{cases}$$ which has derivative $0$ on the open set $(-2,-1)\cup (1,2)$.

Let's assume path-connectedness as suggested in the comments. Then between two points $a,b\in U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ we have a smooth path $$x(t),\;0\le t\le 1$$ By the mean value theorem we have $$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(f(x(t))\bigg)=x'(c)\cdot\nabla f(x(c))=f(x(1))-f(x(0))=f(b)-f(a)$$ for some $c\in (0,1)$. Because the function has $\nabla f=\mathbf{0}$ on $U$ $$f(b)-f(a)=0$$ Therefore the function is constant because $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary.